# Why this program skips the loop?

Tags: c++, string

I can not figure out the problem with this program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;
    char s[5];

    cin>>t;
    cin>>s;

    while(t--){

       char f[100];

       cin>>f;

       cout<<f<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 abcde 
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.100 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I think it should ask for the string f five times and print the string f five times before termination.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide with the output when a string of `length <= 4` is entered for `s` (for example, `abcd`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the terminating null-character, 5-character string is too long to fit into `char s[5];`. In this case, `t` seems *happened* to be just after `s` in the memory and your machine is using little endian, so the terminating null-character, whose value is 0, is overwritten to the least byte of `t` and the value of `t` *happened* to be zero.

To avoid this, you should use `std::string` instead of arrays of `char` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;
    string s;

    cin>>t;
    cin>>s;

    while(t--){

       string f;

       cin>>f;

       cout<<f<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If using arrays of `char` is required, make the input strings short enough or increase buffer size to enable it store all possible input without causing buffer overrun.

Comment: For reading into a char array, `getline` is often better as it takes a length argument.

Comment: Good answer @mikecat